# Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota) - Google BI Engine

Tags: google-bi-engine

I am creating a reservation in google BI engine with the capacity of 2GB but it is throwing an exception of "Resource has been exhausted". 
However, the quota limit for the capacity in beta is 10 GB and I also checked no other resources are provisioned in location "US".

http://take.ms/MjhrD

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: I face the same error here (but instead of using location=US, I try with location=EU).
If I make a reservation of 1GB, then it works. But anything superior to 1GB gives that "Current resource pool for BI reservations is exhausted" error

Answer (score 0):

Note: that should have been fixed. There was extraordinary demand BI Engine capacity in Beta, which exceeded allocated RAM in the region. It has been increased and provisioned since then, so shouldn't be a problem going forward.